# Using "||" in switch statements in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

Part of a Java program I'm making asks the user their home country. Another part uses a switch statement, and I get an error. The error is: `The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String`. Here's the method where the problem occurs:

```
public static String getCountryMessage(String countryName) {
    switch (countryName) {
    case "USA":
        return "Hello, ";
    case "England" || "UK":
        return "Hallo, ";
    case "Spain":
        return "Hola, ";
    case "France":
        return "Bonjour, ";
    case "Germany":
        return "Guten tag, ";
    default:
        return "Hello, ";
    }
}
```

How does one use && and || in a Java switch statement?

Comment: By the way "Hallo" is also used in German. "Guten Tag" is much more formal. Not sure if you want that.

Comment: Sorry java did not have this feature (My old BASIC had it. It also had the possibility for ranges `case 2 To 13`). But such features do not exist in java. `||` can be emulated by fallthrough. (see Answers below).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you can use conditionals like that in switch statements.  It'd be simpler and more straightforward to write this instead:

```
case "England":
case "UK":
    return "Hallo";
```

This is a [fall-through case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) - if your string matches either England or UK, it will return `Hallo`.

Comment: AIFK switch does only allow constants like int. Did I miss something?

Comment: Java 7 allows switching on Strings.

Answer (score 7):

Use the fall-through case:

```
case "England":
case "UK":
    return "Hallo, ";
```